# What HTTP traffic monitor would you recommend for Windows?

Tags: windows, http, traffic, sniffer

I need the sniffer to test network traffic of applications developed by me for Windows and Facebook.

Basic requirements:

- display request and response
- display HTTP headers
- display the time it took to complete HTTP request

Now I'm using HTTP Analyzer.
A very good tool, but it terminates with some error after 10-15 min running on Vista.

Comment: Related on Super User: [How can I monitor all the outgoing HTTP requests from my PC?](https://superuser.com/q/357123/358766)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) if you want to see everything going on in the network.

[Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) if you want to just monitor HTTP/s traffic.

[Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) if you're in Firefox and want a quick plugin just to see the headers.

Also [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) can get you that information too and provides a nice interface when your working on a single page during development.  I've used it to monitor AJAX transactions.

Comment: Correction: Fiddler if you want to monitor *or modify* HTTP *or HTTPS* traffic.

Comment: This answer would be helpful for [this duplicate question on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/357123/358766). Would you mind crossposting this answer?

Comment: Fiddler isn't free.

Comment: Fiddler used to be free, but that's changed since I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 9):

I now use [CharlesProxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) for development, but previously I have used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: +1 for Charles. Fiddler is very good, but some of Charles's other features such as Map Local and Rewrite give it the edge (plus, it's cross-platform).

Comment: FWIW, Fiddler can both map local (see AutoResponder) and trivially rewrite (see the script engine). It only runs on Windows, but you can point any other computer at a Windows machine running Fiddler.

Comment: Extra +1 to Fiddler for being free

Answer (score 7):

Try [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/):

> Wireshark is the world's foremost
>   network protocol analyzer, and is the
>   de facto (and often de jure) standard
>   across many industries and educational
>   institutions.

There is a bit of a learning curve but it is far and away the best tool available.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft Network Monitor (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f)

Comment: To monitor only http traffic you should add a filter like `ProtocolName == "HTTP"` or `tcp.dstport == 80 && http` etc.

Comment: How to get request and response body in the Microsoft Network Monitor

Answer (score 5):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is great when you are only interested in the http(s) side of the communications.  It is also very useful when you are trying to inspect inside a https stream.

Answer (score 4):

I like [TcpCatcher](http://www.tcpcatcher.fr) because it is very simple to use and has a modern interface. It is provided as a jar file, you just download it and run it (no installation process). Also, it comes with a very useful "on the fly" packets modification features (debug mode).

Comment: The link redirects to a malicious site

Comment: The link was wrong ,it is  tcpacher.fr and not tcpcatcher.org. I corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) in most cases, but I have found [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to be less of a hassle when dealing with encrypted data.