# Why doesn't Internet Explorer display a correct XML transform when returning to a page via the back button?

Tags: xml, delphi, internet-explorer

I'm generating some XML data in a Delphi application, in response to an HTTP GET request, using a `TIdHTTPServer` to detect it & send a response. The XML links to an XSLT stylesheet to render the HTML page. This works fine, the page displays OK.

I then click a link in the page to navigate to another level of data, again all OK. The problem is if I then click *back*, the previous page is re-displayed, but some of the data (not all of it) is different, but my server has not received another HTTP GET request to generate the XML. If I click *refresh* in IE, then my server gets an HTTP GET & regenerates the page correctly.

If I use other browsers, it works OK all of the time. I've tried adding META tags to stop the page caching in the XSLT, but it makes no difference. IE doesn't re-request the page.

I'd rather not post specific XML data as its sensitive customer data.

Comment: p.s. thanks Dimitre for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to set correct cache control HTTP headers for your XML source file. See headers description in wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Avoiding_caching

Comment: I've put those into the XSLT used to transform the XML data, the server merely returns the XML which references the XSLT. Do I put these headers into the XML & not the XSLT ?

Comment: HTTP headers are additional attributes which web-server sends together with files. So you have to adjust your web-server settings to set required headers. See server documentation.

Comment: You can use 'Firebug' browser extension or any HTTP traffic monitor to check which headers you currently have. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271768/what-http-traffic-monitor-would-you-recommend-for-windows

Comment: Ah-ha ! Understand that. I put the "no-cache" inside the XSLT transformation thinking it would stop the source XML from caching. I've put it into the server response for the source XML & it now doesn't cache. Answer accepted. Thank you so much.