# Viewing Xbox one network traffic

Tags: charles-proxy, xbox-one

I am trying to view the HTTP traffic going from my Xbox One using charles proxy. However, as Xbox One doesn't allow you to use a proxy this is finding out to be difficult.

I have tried using my laptop's internet connection through ethernet cable from the Xbox One to my laptop, but I cannot see the traffic on Charles.

Does anyone know of a way I can see this traffic?

Comment: What OS do you have?  You should be able to view the traffic, but not with a proxy software.

Comment: i don't think xbox one (or any machine) can determine whether a proxy is used. its plausible that a special header is placed into the http headers, but that would be placed there by the proxy server. several ports need to be open and these are found on http://support.xbox.com/en-CA/xbox-one/networking/network-ports-used-xbox-live. one can easily set up a osx laptop/desktop to share its connection. combine that with a packet sniffer called 'carnivore pe' or some other osx one.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas I'm on mac, but have BootCamp installed so I can use either OS.  I am mainly interested in HTTP requests, how would I go about seeing these from my Xbox One?

Comment: updated my answer with a link that I think would work.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the dev home app for xbox installed on your xbox it is possible to setup a Charles proxy to monitor the HTTP traffic.

Follow these steps to install the dev home:
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-activate-dev-mode-your-xbox-one-console

Once the dev home app is installed you can enable the device portal on your xbox:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-xbox

This is where things get a little hacky, but your going to end up using Charles instead of Fiddler to monitor your devices traffic. You will need to install Fiddler to get a FiddlerRoot.cer (http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/FirefoxHTTPS), which you upload to your xbox through the network page in the xbox device portal. Then you simply enter your laptops IP address in the "Host IP address" field, and the Fiddler port is the port number defined in your Charles Proxy Settings.

Then you press the Enable button, which will prompt you to restart your xbox. Select the Restart button, and once your xbox restart you will begin to see HTTP traffic in Charles.

Answer (score 0):

Get a homebrew router with linux installed.  Then you any linux TCP sniffer tool filtered by IP address to view the traffic.  Similarly, you should be able to do the same in the setup you have now.

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271768/what-http-traffic-monitor-would-you-recommend-for-windows) work for your current setup via bootcamp?

If its connected through wireless, you could also just use a wireless sniffer.  However I imagine you would want to look at the contents so this may pose a hurdle with encryption.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I'm getting confused, or we are talking about different things.

What exactly is a homebrew router?  What would it achieve?  As I say you can't connect to the internet on xbox one via a proxy like you can on the PS4 e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MP4ZcwSHxbw so that you can then see the traffic through charles.  Also when I use my laptop's internet through wi-fi, this doesn't show up on Charles (I'm not sure why).

I don't suppose you could give me a more detailed explanation of what you mean could you?  Thanks!